# Automate drag and drop ImageView to a RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, android-animation

I have an `ImageView` and a `RecyclerView` at top and bottom of an `Activity` respectively.
ImageView can be dragged and dropped in any positions in the RecyclerView, which works fine.
What I would like to do next is that to automate the drag and drop animation when I tapped on RecyclerView items.

Is there any way to create the drag and drop animation without actually doing it with ImageView and clicked item position.

Adapter -

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dragLocation.onAutoDragStart(holder.getAdapterPosition(),view);
                holder.root.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.envoy_orange_corner));
            }
        });
```

Activity -

```
@Override
    public void onAutoDragStart(int position, View view) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(mRlAvatar);
            mRlAvatar.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, mRlAvatar, 0);

            //code for drag and drop animation

    //        mRlAvatar.animate()
    //                .x(view.getX())
    //                .y(view.getY())
    //                .setDuration(1000)
    //                .start();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a `FrameLayout` in activiy layout then avatar view cloned to the exact position and animated to `RecyclerView` item coordinates on long tap.

```
@Override
public void onAutoDragStart(int position, View view) {
    int[] originalPos = new int[2];
    view.getLocationInWindow(originalPos);
    final int x = originalPos[0];
    final int y = originalPos[1];

    int[] originalPosA = new int[2];
    mRlAvatar.getLocationInWindow(originalPosA);
    final int xA = originalPosA[0];
    final int yA = originalPosA[1];

    final View avatarView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.avatar_view, null);
    avatarView.setX(xA);
    avatarView.setY(yA);
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.base_frame)).addView(avatarView);
    avatarView.animate().x(x).y(y).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.base_frame)).removeView(avatarView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
}
```